# Using inductor on PCB component power rails

Tags: pcb, inductor, oscillator, passive-networks

Here is excerpt of a schematic from an FPGA board. It shows some ICs that generate clock signals. This implies a whole lot of switching activity.

[image]

I assume based on what I know about power supply filtering, that the rhombus shaped symbol connecting to IO_1.8V and 3.3V_STB are actually chokes. I am not sure why it says 220ohm rather than something like 220nH. I believe that this forms some sort of filter? The questions I have are:

1. Why is inductor present on power rails when we want to minize inductance on power rails of ICs since more inductance means more ripple noise. We use decoupling capacitors to minimize inductance so putting an inductor on power supply rail appears like a bad idea.
2. What is the frequency response of this LC circuit? It seems that LC circuit is a low pass filter so high frequency signal will not go through since the voltage will drop across the inductor .

Comment: The power supply is not necessarily clean enough not to affect the clock. Decoupling works *both* ways and the ferrite bead is intended to keep noise on the power supply from affecting the clocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not chokes in the traditional sense.

They are ferrite beads. The designator is FB, and ferrite beads are rated for their impedance at 100 MHz, here 220 ohms.

Ferrite beads are used as filters. As they are an impedance at high frequencies, they don't pass high frequency currents, and with capacitors they can be thought as LC low pass filters.

1. Impedance in series means noise is not coupled between supply and load side. So an inductive impedance is extremely good idea between supply and load, as long as the load side capacitors have low inductance and resistance. The clock circuits consume current in narrow peaks at high frequency. The ferrite allows DC to pass but at 100 MHz it has 220 ohms impedance, so high frequencies don't pass through and to the power supply it looks like a DC load. As there are bypass capacitors on the load side, it will provide the required high frequency peak currents so the voltage does not drop much during the current peak. Any sharp voltage ripple at the load side will be less sharp at the supply side of ferrite bead as only lower frequencies can be taken from supply.
2. It's rather complex. As said, the ferrite beads are rated with impedance at 100 MHz. It will have a real component and imaginary component, and due to different ferrite material characteristics, it also has higher resistive part that what the DC resistance is (likely around 0.01 ohms). The exact impedance curve will be shown on data sheet, and combined with the impedance provided by the capacitor, it's even more complex. It is not uncommon to see capacitors on both sides of a ferrite bead for even better filtering, called a Pi network.

Comment: I think a capacitor on both sides shall form a Pi filter network. Is that correct? I believe a pi filter has benefit of a much faster roll of but am not sure entirely.

Comment: Since the capacitor is supplying the current when the voltage rail on the IC has ripples, won't it actually filter the ripples anyway since it discharges gradually which makes the ferrit bead redundant?

Comment: Yes for Pi network. The ferrite bead is not redundant if you remove it you have no Pi network and even with capacitors the peak currents are drawn from everywhere through PCB wires and the voltage drop/ripple is also seen everywhere on board. The ferrite bead decouples the load from supply so high load currents run only locally in a tight loop. Ferrite bead is much better even if PCB wiring has inductance.

Comment: I am confused between inductor, choke and ferrite bead. I think they were all basically the same thing. I will do some digging at my end to find out.

Comment: I assume that it is considered a good practice to use ferrite bead on the power rail of oscillators to prevent the noise from being coupled to other parts of the design? I thought just having a lot of capacitors in parallel would still get rid of the noise.

Comment: Coiling a wire makes an inductor. An inductor that is used as a current-limiting choke may be called a choke. A wire coil over a ferrite material or single wire passing through a ferrite ring (bead) makes a ferrite inductor. Yes ferrites are good thing, they allow you to pass radiated and conducted EMI tests so your device does not send out EMI and does not get disturbed by receiving EMI from other devices.

Comment: ok, now the ferrite bead used here is "742792780" from Wurth Electronics. The question I can't get answer to is, how was this specific component chosen for use on the PCB as the ferrite bead and why is ferrite bead not present on all clock sources on all FPGA boards. Should I post a new question on forum for this?

Comment: @quantum231 I think you still may not get an answer to why that specific component was chosen or why any ferrite with 220 ohms at 100MHz. Maybe their previous board used these successfully and they used the same component again. Maybe there was annoying ripple on prototype and they just tried whatever they had and it went into production. Sometimes, there is no engineering involved why some component has some value as long as it is sufficient and good enough for the job with sufficient margin. You use the parts you are familiar with. Like same as asking why most bypass capacitors are 100nF.

Answer (score 2):

**FB15** and **FB16** are ferrite beads, or possibly surface-mount ferrite. Yes, they have inductance, but are very lossy inductors. They are so lossy that their resistance at high frequency dominates inductance.
Rather than specify inductance, the combined inductance and resistance \$Z\$ is specified, usually at 100 MHz. So I'd guess that impedance at 100 MHz is 220 ohms, much of which is actually resistance.

At DC, these have low resistance, below an ohm.

The configuration is a low-pass filter when combined with capacitors. You would not find a ferrite bead feeding DC into one of these oscillators without at least one bypass capacitor from chip Vdd to GND.

These bypass capacitors have very low internal resistance, but usually have some tiny inductance. Resonances of inductance and capacitance of the various components that feed DC power to the chip are inevitable, and quenching them becomes a game of whack-a-mole.
The ferrite bead's lossy nature helps calm resonances on a chip's power line. One does not strive for well-defined pass band and stop band in this kind of service. What's important is that the low-pass stop band has no bumps that let some frequencies through. A gradual transition from pass-band to stop band is acceptable.

Comment: How is this structure designed? We start with a ferrite bead and then choose a capacitor or the other way around? How is cut off frequency chosen?

Comment: One's focus is on stop band attenuation in the 10's, 100's MHz region up to GHz, not so much on corner frequency. Personally, I choose the bypass capacitor(s) first, and then consider how ferrite might enhance attenuation in the stop band region. For feeding DC to a 50 MHz oscillator, think of not only 50 MHz., but its harmonics too. Don't expect a ferrite bead to make much impact on a switching DC supply under a MHz.

Answer (score 0):

The inductance in the ferrite beads is undesirable and considered parasitic. Ideal ferrite beads have zero inductance - they act purely resistive, with resistance rising with frequency up to the peak suppression frequency.

In fact, ferrite beads seeing heavy transient loads may have enough inductance to damage components with their inductive spike.

For the application you’re showing, inductors wouldn’t be a good idea, since they don’t dissipate the energy very much, just limit it’s transfer. When feeding a clock generator you want something that will absorb the square wave current leaking through the supply line past the decoupling capacitors.

Comment: For the first time I have found that there is a difference between ferrite bead and inductor. I am a RTL design verification person by the way. When you resistance, it implies a quantity that exists at DC. The AC equivalent of this is reactance. Both of these are combined to give inductance. I do not understand what you mean by the statement "resistance rising with frequency up to the peak suppression frequency."